# Electron externalDisplay bounds

Tags: node.js, electron, screen, display

in the electron Doc (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/screen)

why do they add 
`x: externalDisplay.bounds.x + 50,
y: externalDisplay.bounds.y + 50`

the +50 to the `x` and `y` of the window ?

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  let displays = electron.screen.getAllDisplays()
  let externalDisplay = displays.find((display) => {
    return display.bounds.x !== 0 || display.bounds.y !== 0
  })

  if (externalDisplay) {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
      x: externalDisplay.bounds.x + 50,
      y: externalDisplay.bounds.y + 50
    })
    win.loadURL('https://github.com')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can test this code to find the solve for this quistion:

```
var scr = screen.getDisplayMatching(trayBounds)
console.warn("getDisplayMatching-x-y",scr.bounds);
```